# I'm getting the error "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0" in .NET Core 3.1 app

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-3.1

The latest version of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" is 2.2.0, so I'm not sure where it's getting 3.1.0.0.

I've gone through all of my .csproj files, and all of them are referencing 2.2.0.  I'm not sure where else to look.

I have 3 different applications (solutions) that share projects, and this is happening on all of them at different times.  One of them works if I publish it from VS, but I'd like to try to get them deployed using Azure DevOps release pipeline.

Comment: Please clarify your question and your title.

Comment: Thank you Nikola, but I don't believe that your adjusted title is what I'm asking.  I'm wondering how I can stop the error from even happening in the first place, especially since I'm not referencing it anywhere.

Comment: Then please make the appropriate adjustments to give more context and details as to what is happening. as a quick troubleshooting you might want to check if some package isn't referencing newer/older versions of what you are using at the moment. To do that, you can open the page for each nuget package, and see what it references under the "Dependencies" section of the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions` has moved to [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions)
for versions 2.x and above, all 3.x versions are there, as well as 5.x versions.
the 2.x version is most likely left in the old nuget package as a compatibility package or similar.

Comment: It looks like I have both "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" and "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions", referenced in my projects.  Could they be conflicting?

Comment: Absolutely. If you are on .net core 3.1 choose the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions` 3.1 package. if you are on 2.1, choose the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions` or the other one, depending what's already used.

Comment: That kind of worked.  It got 2 of my 3 projects back up and running.  The 3rd still has the same error, but I'll investigate further separately.  You definitely helped me out.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Yeah, So this answer doesn't seem to be complete. I'm trying to access `IWebHostEnvironment`, which is [in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` of which there is a v5.0.2](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v5.0.2/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/IWebHostEnvironment.cs), but there's no nuget package for that... It seems I have to include the **whole** aspnetcore package!!

Comment: @JHBonarius Please read my answer. the package has moved to another package. And you might be trying to access older interface that doesn't exist in the same namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostenvironment?view=aspnetcore-5.0) `IWebHostEnvironment` to definitely part of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll`, and it has only been introduced since .net core 3.0, so it's not an old interface. IMHO confirmed [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2020/Feb/26/Working-with-IWebHostEnvironment-and-IHostingEnvironment-in-dual-targeted-NET-Core-Projects)...

Comment: As you can see in [the sources of `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/src) `IWebHostEnvironment` is _not_ there. Just trying to say that your answer is not complete: not *everything* of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions` has been moved to `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions`.