# .NET Core 3.1 web API builds fine locally, but gets errors when deploying via Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, .net-core

I had a similar problem a couple weeks ago:

[I'm getting the error "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0" in .NET Core 3.1 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65064208/im-getting-the-error-microsoft-aspnetcore-hosting-abstractions-version-3-1-0/65064281?noredirect=1#comment115027432_65064281)

I can run it from Visual Studio 2019 locally with no issues, but whenever I try to run it after deploying via Azure DevOps, I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
   at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_ReturnType()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StartupLoader.FindMethod(Type startupType, String methodName, String environmentName, Type returnType, Boolean required)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StartupLoader.HasConfigureServicesIServiceProviderDelegate(Type startupType, String environmentName)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<UseStartup>b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at KindRegards.Web.Api.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Api/Program.cs:line 10
```

I don't fully understand how all of this ties together, so I tried adding:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="5.0.0" />
```

but that didn't work.  I have other "Microsoft.Extension" packages that are using version 3.1.8, so I tried matching those by adding:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="3.1.8" />
```

But then I couldn't run it locally, and I get this error:

```
NU1605  Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions from 5.0.0 to 3.1.8. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 KindRegards.Web.Api -> KindRegards.Plugins.PaymentProcessors.GreenMoney -> Microsoft.Extensions.Http 5.0.0 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 5.0.0) 
 KindRegards.Web.Api -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 3.1.8)    Web.Api Z:\Projects\KindRegards\src\Api\Web.Api.csproj  1
```

I'm not sure how to even begin digging into this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your deployment mode set to? When I switched to .NET 5.0 and upgraded all the nuget packages in our solution, I had to change the deployment mode setting to "Framework Dependent" instead of "Self Contained". I had to wipe the server directory manually, and re-deploy with the change. Might check your deployment mode?

Comment: I'm relatively new to using DevOps + Azure, so I'm not sure where to look for that.

Comment: Had problem in my local Visual Studio deploying it via Publish. For whatever reason, DevOps was not updating the .dll versions on the server, so I manually deleted it all. Then I published from my local and noticed it copied all kinds of stuff I dont even use to my server. I noticed the publish settings were "selfcontained=true", which it should be false, otherwise it copies many wrong .dlls to the destination. It's worth checking to see how your stuff is getting published, even from DevOps. This broke for us in .NET 5.0 migration. Look for .pubxml file locally or publish task on DevOps.

Comment: When "selfcontained=true" from my local VS publish, it copied hundreds of .NET Framework .dlls which were not using .NET 5.0 yet. Once I told it that deployment mode "framework dependent" instead of "self contained", my .NET 5.0 application started working and truly using my NuGet packages w/ .NET 5.0 (it was fooling us for a few days). After checking in those changes , it seems to still be working, even from DevOps perspective. I have never had to deal with deployment mode either, but apparently .NET 5.0 breaks it, atleast for my team it did.

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me before while using `Azure DevOps` and the solution was to check what is `Azure DevOps` using and I matched the project with it, **I mean your target should be the version that `Azure DevOps` agent is using.**

I do not remember exactly, but most likely I downgraded my app version to match the Azure DevOps.

This happens generally when your Visual Studio automatic updates are enabled so your .Net Core nugets become more up to date than the ones used in Azure DevOps

Comment: The "Build Pipeline" builds the solution just fine, I don't get any errors.  Then I deploy that artifact using the "Release Pipeline".  I only get the error after I try to start the build results after it's deployed.

Comment: @Jason Thuli where you try to publish? Azure?

Comment: I've tried 2. An Azure App Service, and a Digital Ocean droplet.  Both using Linux hosting.

Comment: @JasonThuli check your Release Pipeline task settings. It might be "self contained", which would cause non 5.0 dlls to be carried over, causing a versioning conflict

Comment: @JasonThuli have you looked at the artifacts and verified that the correct version exists? Is .NET 5.0 installed on the server? If you look at your artifacts/output, is there extra junk there (like mbs worth of stuff you dont recognize or that your app does not use?).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you created your project targeting .Net 5, which is great. Restore your project the way you had it originally and add another step to your pipeline where you install .Net 5.0.100. I think the link below may help.

[Azure Pipeline Failing in dotnet build, need to upgrade to latest .net core version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65314492/azure-pipeline-failing-in-dotnet-build-need-to-upgrade-to-latest-net-core-vers)

Comment: So, this is why it's confusing.  We can't upgrade to .NET 5 because of some 3rd party dependencies that haven't been upgraded yet.  Also, our build pipeline is using 3.1.x, and it succeeds.  I don't get the error until I attempt to run the site from the server (which is obviously after the build pipeline on DevOps).